# Quadrupedal super predators

Tags: biology, creature-design, evolution, fauna, dinosaurs

Could a quadrupedal carnivore reach similar sizes to that of large theropods. I know crocodilians technically count, but they're very low to the ground and have sprawled out limbs, so could a quadrupedal predator, with limbs directly below it's body, reach dinosaurian proportions? I'm looking for a stock of erect legged predators which could evolve to became large enough to hunt and kill animals as large as indricotheres and hadrosaurs. Most preferably a therapsid or crocodylomorph.

Comment: Might you be thinking of [dimetrodons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimetrodon)? As it turns out they're more closely related to mammals than the extant therapods, (My auto-correct insisted on "therapists". :(  ) You could add some details about your world, a bit of context, if you please.

Comment: Please take the [tour] wyrm, and when you have (really quite a bit) of spare-time, read-up in the [help] about how we work. Welcome to Wbse.

Comment: What is a ther**a**pod and how is it different from a ther**o**pod? (The largest known fossil mammalian land-dwelling carnivores are [*Simbakubwa kutokaafrika*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simbakubwa), about twice as heavy as a modern polar bear, and possibly [*Andrewsarchus mongoliensis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrewsarchus).)

Comment: ^^sorry, but no. I'm thinking of something at least 20-30 feet long and 14 feet tall, and dimetrodons are way to small. Being related to mammals is not exactly what I'm looking for, just large quadrupedal carnivores in general. As for my world, It's basically earth, but with a variety of species that didn't live at the same time period together, so attempting to find a candidate for an animal that could evolve into the super carnivore

Comment: ^ whoops I mispelled

Comment: A tetrapod carnivore with the limbs below the body **is** a mammal, or at best one of the para-reptilian ancestors of mammals. (And those para-reptilian proto-mammals were not all that large.) (And the problem with super-carninvores is that they need a large population of super-herbivores to eat. There is a reason why the largest carnivores are the size they are.)

Comment: I assert again, please [edit] the question to tell us about your world (and requirements) in specific terms.

Comment: @AlexP *Andrewsarchus* is a lot bigger than *Simbakubwa*, and *Simbakubwa* isn't even the biggest member of its clade. *Simbakubwa* is a member of a group that also includes the larger *Megistotherium* and *Hyainailouros*. Exactly how big these animal were is controversial but at the last big vertebrate paleontology meeting there was some research that suggested that the largest of these was "only" about 150% the weight of a polar bear (400 kg) and that older estimates are way too high. *Andrewsarchus* was like 1200 kg.

Comment: ^^ I'm mostly in the development stage right now so the specific I can get is, one it's a tropical earth like planet, in which many species of mega fauna, from several periods, large crocodilimorphs and therapsids as examples. As for the super herbivores, the largest herbivores are derived from stocks of ungulates and small ornithischians, which have become close to the size of there groups largest representatives, that being pacatherium and Shantungosaurus. As for specifics on predators, I'm simply looking for any carnivorous, erect legged, animal which could produce large predators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word: Yes. The Cenozoic terrestrial crocodiliform *Barinasuchus arveloi* belongs to [a clade of erect-legged crocodilians](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/02724634.2012.646833) [and could grow to be about the same size as the tyrannosaur *Daspletosaurus* or *Albertosaurus*](https://web.a.ebscohost.com/ehost/detail/detail?vid=0&sid=113b0978-0126-4b53-ac07-84f69c9c30e6%40sdc-v-sessmgr03&bdata=JkF1dGhUeXBlPWlwLHNoaWImc2l0ZT1laG9zdC1saXZl#AN=118331146&db=a9h), making it the largest known Cenozoic land predator. *[Razanandrongobe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Razanandrongobe)* belongs to a closely-related group and may have also had an erect gait and been as large or slightly smaller.

Answer (score 0):

**What's wrong with "basic" crocodilians?**

As far as I understand, you're not looking for a final product of a predator to just size up and include, but one that would make sense as an ancestral species of your super predator. If that's the case and you don't want mammals, why not crocodiles or other crocodilian? The fact we have specimens like [kaprosuchus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprosuchusl), which could gallop and had a mostly terrestrial lifestyle, or [Deinosuchus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deinosuchus) a species which included adults as long as 39 feet with one of the most powerful bites in history and which hunted dinosaurs,show just how diverse this group of animals got.

My point is: kaprosuchus is just an example of how evolution can reshape these animals, and if you're not looking for a finished product, it might actually be a better choice regarding subversion of disbelief, and if you think it's unrealistic for an animal originally not that big to grow to the proportions you desire, you might want to take a look at [big T's great great grandpa](https://www.sciencealert.com/the-legendary-tyrannosaurus-rex-evolved-from-a-teeny-tiny-ancestor).

Regarding the question "could it grow"? Depending on the animal, yes it could, since we've had crocodilians larger than T-Rex (Spinosaurus might also be an option here, since new research indicates it might have moved in a more quadrupedal style while out of the water).